# Why my navbar-dark bg-dark classes won't work on bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i'm new to bootstrap.I tried adding navigation bar to html page using bootstrap classes but .navbar-dark .bg-dark or .navbar-light .bg-light tags aren't working.

Here's my code

''''

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

''''

Comment: Works fine for me.  Have you added some css that may  be affecting/overiding the bootstrap navigation css?

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, please be sure to upvote / accept an answer to close the post and to show others the solution if they have a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a link to the CDN (Content Delivery Network) within your header tags.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```